$\mathbb{C} $ with the lexicographic ordering : Does this set have the least upper bound property?
Rudin Exercise Chapter 1 number 9:
Consider the set of complex numbers with the lexicographic ordering. Does this set have the least upper bound property?
I have seen answers that say yes but I think there are  counterexamples so I'm wondering if my answer is correct.
(The lexicographic ordering is the following:
Suppose $z=a+bi$ , $w=c+di$. Define $z<w$ if $a<c$, and also if $a=c$ but $b<d$.)

Cf. this question

Suppose $\mathbb{C} $ does have the least upper bound property when given the lexicographic ordering.
Consider the set $E = \{1+i,1+2i,1+3i,\ldots \}$
$E$ is bounded above by $2$ so let $t$ be the least upper bound of $E$.
First suppose $\Re(t) > 1$. Then we can always choose another number $u$ such that $$\Re(u) = 1+
\frac{\Re(t) -1 }{2} , \Im(u) = \Im(t)$$
Since $u$ has real part greater than $1$, it is an upper bound of $E$. But since $u < t$, this contradicts the assumption that $t$ is the least upper bound of $E$.
But then $\Re(t) \le 1$. Then $t$ cannot be upper bound of $E$. So there is no least upper bound for $E$ after all.
